# How do i remove the last character from a string after the last "."

Tags: python, string, ip

Im working on a python scipt which gets and Ip and calculates the brodcast which just removes the last digest of the ip after the last "." and replaces them with 255

```
input = "192.168.0.100" 
input = #string operation
print(input)
```

Comment: "str.split" or str.rfind" can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input = "192.168.0.100" 
loc = input.rfind('.')
inputShort = input[1:loc]
print(loc)
print(inputShort)
```

`rfind` finds the last incidence of the "." character and `inputShort` is then all characters up until, but excluding the last ".".

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast address is not always going to be just 255 as last digest. That would be true only if the prefix len is /24 (or mask is 255.255.255.0).

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> input = "192.168.0.100"
>>> from re import sub
>>> sub('(.[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$', '.255', input)
'192.168.5.255'
```